# mongodb listen to localhost and lan ip only

Tags: mongodb, networking

I have an Ubuntu server with mongodb installed. Is it possible to configure mongodb in such a way that I can connect to it using **only** localhost and its LAN IP address.

The default mongo configuration works fine for connecting using localhost:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

If I change to the LAN IP, then I am only able to connect using that IP, and not using localhost:

```
bind_ip = 10.10.10.10
```

If I try to add both, then I get an `address in use` error and doesn't start:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10
```

If I remove the bind_ip setting, then both work, but I am also able to connect with the servers external IP (which I do not want).

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10
```

So, how can I tell mongo to listen on the local interface, but allow connections from both localhost and its LAN IP?

Comment: Setting `bind_ip=localhost,<LAN IP>` is the correct MongoDB setting. Can you include the complete error message from the log? Also, excerpting all the net settings from the config file may be helpful. What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: This is interesting. I tried reproducing the error again using your suggestion (just to make sure) - and it worked without a problem... After a bunch of tests I realized what the difference is. Note the **space** after the comma in my post. That's the problem. Removing the space it works just the way I want it to. Interesting. (By the way its a clean install of 2.6.6 - no other config changes).

Comment: That's unfortunate because I noticed the space and tried to reproduce the problem by including the extra space. Worked fine for me. I realize now the trick is you are using the old config file format and not the new YAML one. I used the YAML format. Glad to hear the problem is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of @wdberkeley's comment, I realized that the problem was the space after the , in the list of IP addresses the bind to. However, it seems that this issue only affects the old config file format (not YAML).

```
# This Works:
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,10.10.10.10

# This doesn't work:
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind to address 0.0.0.0 this will allow it to answer regardless of the IP address being used and even on machines that have multiple network cards with different IP addresses

Comment: True. The only problem with that solution is that it means that the server listens on the public IP as well. Of course I could solve this using a firewall, but I was mainly wondering if there is any way to configure mongodb to behave the way I want it to.